# Why is it logically possible to calculate $P(A' \cup B)$ in a non-mutually exclusive event?

Tags: probability

In a non-mutually exclusive event, events $A$ and $B$ will overlap in the Venn diagram. When considering the probability of $B,$ I must also consider the region on the diagram where events $A$ and $B$ overlap (i.e. $P(A \cap B)$). However, this will mean that I'm also considering the probability that event A will take place. How is it logically possible for me to both consider event A happening and not happening?

[Note: Please don't give too complicated of an answer. This is only British high school maths.]

Comment: Did you mean $P(A'\cap B)$ in the title?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear, but I *think* you're asking about the equation $$P(B)=P(A\cap B)+P(A'\cap B),$$ where "$A'$" denotes the complement of $A$.

The reason you can consider both $A$ and $A'$ is that you're asking two *separate* questions:

- What's the probability of "$A$ and $B$"?
- What's the probability of "(not $A$) and $B$"?

For instance, suppose I roll a fair six-sided coin, $A$ is "get an even number," $A'$ is "get an odd number," and $B$ is "get a number $>3$." Then:

- $P(A\cap B)$ is the probability of getting an even number $>3$, that is, either $4$ or $6$: this is just $1\over 3$.
- $P(A'\cap B)$ is the probability of getting an odd number $>3$, that is, $5$: this is just $1\over 6$.
- So we should expect $P(B)={1\over 3}+{1\over 6}={1\over 2}$, which is indeed the case. Certainly the two events $A\cap B$ and $A'\cap B$ are incompatible, meaning they can't both *happen* at once, but we can certainly *calculate each of their probabilities* at once!

Comment: Perfect answer. Nailed my confusion. 'We're asking 2 separate questions', and the example was also great.